# Google OAuth 2.0 User id datatype for MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm implementing Google OAuth 2.0 and noticed that the unique user id returned by Google OAuth is **21 digits** long. I thought **BIGINT(20)** would be enough for this need, but I'm confused now on seeing the length of the user id returned by Google OAuth. Any ideas on how I should go about this ?

Comment: Well, seeing as it's larger than the largest integer data type you're going to have to store it as a string. It doesn't really matter though, since you're not going to be performing any math on it in this case.

Comment: Do you think TEXT or varchar is good for storing this OAuth data ? I haven't done this before and I'm not sure using TEXT will be appropriate for something like OAuth user id.

Comment: No. `TEXT` columns are best suited for bulk data storage, use a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For saving the id, you should use varchar, beacuse as the data you are trying to save is from 3rd party, you can't be certain if the value will be numeric only(though google user id is numeric only but the convention is still not in our control).

Comment: Even varchar needs a maximum length in mysql. Is there any ideal varchar length for these kind of data returned ? Or, is TEXT preferred ?

Comment: there is no ideal length, i have used length 500, for storing google user ids in my data structure. but it may not be same for all networks.

Comment: though don't use TEXT, as the user id wont ever be too large

Comment: i have settled for a varchar(50) as of now. thanks for the inputs

Comment: @Jhanvi Since the id will need to be unique and searched, is varchar better for sorting/search than bigint?

Comment: bigInt cannot store the size of what a token ID can be.

Comment: You may as well do VARCHAR(255) as there is no practical difference between 50 and 255, other than that the database will then truncate anything above 50 characters. They use the same memory and storage.