# What data can I save in my database to verify a user with Google sign in API?

Tags: google-signin

I need to store data related to a (Google) user in my database. I tried to store the id_token, but later found out that the part after the '.' changed. What can be used instead, or can I just save the part infront of the "." from the id_token?

Comment: Use the 'sub' field of the ID token, it is invariant for the Google user account: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks Steven Soneff

> Use the 'sub' field of the ID token, it is invariant for the Google user https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint

The ID token have three parts; the header, body and signature, divided by a '.' (header.body.signature). Each part is encoded with base64. If you decode the body, you will get a JSON like this:

```
{  
   "iss":"https://accounts.google.com",
   "at_hash":"xxx",
   "aud":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "sub":"xxx",
   "email_verified":true,
   "azp":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "email":"xxx@gmail.com",
   "iat":xxx,
   "exp":xxx
}
```

> ...you can safely retrieve and use the user's unique Google ID from the sub claim

So you can save the `sub` in your database to identify your user

Comment: How can I safely set it to MySQL database as `id`. integer for `sub` is too large, and it will disrupt the local login auto increment. or should it be separated to another table

Comment: @RyanAquino I am in NO WAY an expert on databases, and the different shapes the `sub` can take aren't defined anywhere that I can find. But you can use a ´varchar(21)` instead to store it as a string. The number might be even longer in some cases, so you might have to use a value higher than 21.

EDIT: Nvm I'm apparently an expert, at least I am in this case :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/19409345/3165622