# How do I save a user to a database after OAuth with Google Sign In API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin

My question is similar to [What data can I save in my database to verify a user with Google sign in API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989373/what-data-can-i-save-in-my-database-to-verify-a-user-with-google-sign-in-api)

I've built Google Sign In correctly and I get a response from the API like this:

```
{  
   "iss":"https://accounts.google.com",
   "at_hash":"xxx",
   "aud":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "sub":"xxx",
   "email_verified":true,
   "azp":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "email":"xxx@gmail.com",
   "iat":xxx,
   "exp":xxx
}
```

The SO link above says to save the sub field as this is a unique identifier. I can save the email/sub no problem. My question is: How do I allow this user to sign in next time with an email/password form, if they choose to do this, versus OAuth? I guess I could force them to sign in thru OAuth, then verify they're signed in and have them create a password, but I don't know if that's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The "sub" parameter is only guaranteed unique for the "iss" parameter. So the combination of "iss" and "sub" is globally unique.

If you **MUST** store a password you will need to ask the user. Some apps put in a random-complex password for every user as some application frameworks require a password. This may be helpful if they forget they used Google to sign in for you to do you due diligence in assigning a temporary password for the user with the email address.

You should of course consider that the email address is globally unique at any given time, but could be reassigned in some cases.

Comment: so if I understand correctly: I could store "iss" + "sub", and when the user does OAuth, compare the returned "iss" + "sub" to my database "iss" + "sub", and allow access if they match. My problem is: How can I validate who the user is to then have them create a password? Typically websites require you to input your existing password to update a password. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are using google-signin you are Trusting that Google has Validated the user and they are who they said they were. Google does all the password management. You may ask for the user for YET ANOTHER password and manage passwords if you wish without google-signin. Some site offer both options.